# Can I get the TestComplete version number from script?

Tags: testcomplete8

In order to work with the Network Suite it is important to have the same version of TestComplete installed on all systems. Can I check the version number from script? I am thinking about storing it in a NetWork Suite variable in order to compare the TestComplete version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Sys.Process("TestComplete").FileVersionInfo` to get the full version number, e.g. 9.0.1312.7, or you can use `Sys.Process("TestComplete").FileVersionInfo.MajorPart`, `MinorPart`, `BuildPart` and `PrivatePart` to get the corresponding parts of the version number.